# How to tell what newline is used in Git repository

Tags: c++, git, newline

I'm currently developing with a bunch of guys using Linux, while I'm on a Windows machine running VS C++. Whenever I want to merge my changes, practically all docs get changed as well, without my commit containing them, and all changes being empty.

My sneaking suspicion is that the linux guys are uploading CRLF newlines (does that make any sense???). If I look at the raw view on Bitbucket, and copy paste that to Notepad++, that's also what I see. Visual Studio, by default, uploads only LF newlines. However, I'd like to make sure I'm not stupidly forgetting something, because it just seems so odd. I'd be more forward with them, but I'm obviously pretty junior. Thanks

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/

Comment: Yes I'm aware of how to handle the line endings, I'm just not sure what line endings are currently being used. I'm told they're LF, but copy paste reveals CRLF.

Comment: Fire up Vim and run `:set ff?`.

Comment: You can use `git grep --name-only $'\r\n'` (tested with git bash on windows) to find all files which contain a windows style newline.